# How to overwrite the theme in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Can any one help me on how to overwrite the theme in Shopify. Is there any option to create custom child theme under main theme and write custom codes into the activated child theme? Or there is another way to customized the theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of child themes in shopify. Shopify refers to copies as duplicates, and a theme is either published or unpublished.

Before editing a themes structure make a duplicate and this is generally what should be worked on instead of the published(live) until all changes are done and the theme previews look ready.

If used to version control software(git) there are tools to automate the upload/download so you can work with your preferred editor locally.

So If you want customize the theme then just create a duplicate copy of the main the theme and do your all changes in the duplicate theme and see the all changes using theme preview option. After completing all of the changes, you can publish the duplicate theme and it will work as an active theme.